# PHPLists integration in wordpress 4.5.3

Tags: wordpress, newsletter, phplist

I tried using wp phplist plugin, but i am not getting any confirmation email. Is there any other way??
i also tried using form action:

```
<form method="post" action="http:/neparica.com/lists/?p=subscribe&id=34" name="subscribeform">
```